# How to change the asyncStorage value in a screen to the drawer instantly?

Tags: react-native

I've combined drawer and stack navigation. And I have AsyncStorage to store a value in a screen and this value is used/displayed in DrawerScreen. The value is stored but it doesn't instantly display in drawerScreen. I've to close the app and reopen it to see the value change in the drawer. How can I change the value instantly in a drawer after it is stored in a screen

```
export default (DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: StackNav
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <DrawerScreen {...props} />
  }
));


const StackNav = StackNavigator(
  {
      SearchLocation: {
          screen: SearchLocation
        }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "SearchLocation"
  }
);
```

DrawerScreen.js

```
_getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    const getLocation = await AsyncStorage.getItem("changedLocation");
    this.setState({
      currentLocation: getLocation
    });
};

componentDidMount() {
    this._getCurrentLocation();
}

render() {
    return (
        <Text>
            {this.state.currentLocation != ""
              ? this.state.currentLocation
              : "Choose Location Manually"}
        </Text>
    )
}
```

SearchLocation.js

```
_currentLocationAsync = async item => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("changedLocation", item);
};

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._currentLocationAsync(item.item.name)}>
    <Text>{item.item.name}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Strictly speaking "instantly" is impossible because of the asynchronous nature of the `AsyncStorage`. The question is, what delay is acceptable? Maybe you should reconsider using `AsyncStorage` for this feature.

Comment: I doubt you missed to notify DrawerScreen.js after location update. Implement a listener for this.

Comment: Can you please show an example or sample for this @Nizam, so I can too update in my app for the same.

Comment: @MaxPevsner how much delay? now it nvr works unless the app is reopened.

Comment: @Nizam how to implement a listener here? Can you please make it clear or give an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should notify the Drawer component about the location update. There are many ways to implement a listener. I'd use the `EventEmiter` for this.
You can read in depth about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).

The flow would be like, in the root component, we have this emitter object.

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this._emitter = new EventEmitter();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._emitter.removeAllListeners();
}
```

Now, you can pass this emitter through props to any child component that has to emit or listen to events

```
<ComponentA emitter={this._emitter} />
<ComponentB emitter={this._emitter} />
```

When the change in component A happens, it simply calls

```
this.props.emitter.emit('eventName', arg);
```

On component B, we have to set the listener, as such:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.emitter.addListener('eventName', (arg) => {
    // this block of code executes when 'eventName' is emitted with argument 'arg'
  });
}
```